# Dedicated memcache items vanishing

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I built an application in PHP on Google App Engine and in order to improve performance began using memcache to cache templates. It works really well as expected however I began seeing that items were disappearing from the shared cache after a few hours.

The documentation states that the shared memcache is provided on a best effort basis and items will be expired if memory becomes an issue. To be clear, we are storing about 20 key/value pairs that are each about 10k.

So assuming that these items were being expired because it was in a shared memcache, I upgraded to a 1 Gig dedicated memcache for our application.

My code is pretty simple and straight forward:

```
$memcached = new Memcached();
$memcached->set('mykey', 'mydata', 1296000);
```

The above code should be setting that key and data with an expiration of 15 days. GAE docs indicate that the maximum is 30 days.

When I run the code it works great and sets the key/data as expected. However when I go to bed and wake up in the morning, what does the memcache viewer in the application admin say?

> Oldest item age: 1 hour(s) 46 min(s) 25 second(s)

What the heck? There is no code that is flushing or deleting, it's a dedicated memcache.

What am I doing wrong? It really seems like something is causing the memcache to expire prematurely. This is a very very low volume application so from the time I set this to the time I checked it (according to the logs) there was only 1 visit (approximately 1 hour and 46 minutes ago).

When an instance shuts down if it's the last resident instance does it clear the memcache?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Seems weird. Try setting it to `0` to see if the items are cached forever. The 30 days by the way should only be a max when using seconds. With a timestmap it's possible to set a larger expire time

Answer (score 2):

Does this happen every night? You may just have been unlucky.

The cache will be flushed if a backend server is restarted. e.g. for a software update, server crash.

Memcache is not written to disk so your code needs to handle this case, but it should happen infrequently.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be what you think it is, that field might not be indicator that your item is vanished.

> A particularly interesting statistic is the “oldest item age.” This is a bit of a misnomer: it's actually the amount of time since the last access of the least recently accessed item, not the full age of that item.

This is not in GAE doc, I found this in Programming Google Appengine book.